# Is there a way to collect user emails using Firebase?

Tags: firebase

I know there's authentication feature, but that looks like it's used for users who are verified. If I want to gather user emails that are unverified (say from "Coming Soon! Leave your email, and we will notify you once complete"), is there any Firebase-way of handling this?

One obvious way would be to set up a Firestore, but I was wondering if Firebase supports this too, and perhaps support other features such as conversion rate (how many unverified emails sign up) etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase has no product or built-in mechansim for this.  You will have to build it yourself.